# Fiddler Not Capturing Traffic from iOS Device after Update

Tags: fiddler

This morning I was able to capture https traffic on the version of Fiddler I had installed. I was prompted about a Fiddler update available. I clicked the "Next time" option. After closing fiddler and reopening a few minutes later the update was automatically installed (v4.6.20172.31233, 64-bit). Following that update, I am not able to take any traces from my iOS device. I am on a work computer capturing https traffic from my iPhone to monitor a mobile app.

It should also be noted that I'm unable to capture any traffic or visit any web pages on my iPhone when going through the IP and port 8888 setup with Fiddler. Seems like all data is blocked (even when I'm not attempting to capture https with a trusted certificate).

I have attempted a few things:

1. Went through these steps (which I had done months ago to originally setup fiddler), and it didn't resolve the situation: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS
2. I checked my Tools > Options and everything seems to be configured the same as it was previously.
3. I double, triple and quadruple confirmed that my iPhone's IP Address and port are correctly matching what fiddler shows when I hover the mouse over the "Online" icon. I confirmed that I'm on the same wifi network on both my laptop and iPhone.
4. I removed the trusted certificate from my iPhone, but could not download a new one because when I go to ipv4.fiddler:8888 the page does not load. "Safari cannot find the page" and neither can Chrome (from my iPhone). FiddlerMachineIP:8888 loads on my laptop browser, but not my iPhone browser. (I didn't post full http:// links on this post because I have a new stack overflow account and it won't let me yet)
5. I downloaded the certificate plugin for iOS once more.
6. I reset my Fiddler Root Certificate by selecting Tools > Options > HTTPS tab > Actions > Reset All Certificates.
7. I attempted step 4 above again, no success
8. I closed and reopened fiddler multiple times between each step to restart it, but no success.
9. Restarted my laptop and iPhone (because why not?)

Do you have any suggestions for what else I can try? Any help is much appreciated. The only thing that was changed was the version of Fiddler. After that, I attempted to run through all the steps above. Currently I'm in a situation where I cannot download the certificate to trust on my iPhone. I don't know what is preventing me from doing that step.

Edit: I reinstalled fiddler and went through all the setup pages. It didn't seem to fix the situation. My phone for some reason will not load the page necessary to download the certificate (ipv4.fiddler:8888)

Answer (score 3):

Try checking the certificate's full trust settings at Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings. Make sure the DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot is enabled for full trust.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this and unfortunately I'm not seeing traffic. My issue was with getting the ipv4.fiddler:8888 link to load on my phone to download the certificate. In the meantime I downloaded it on my computer, emailed it to myself, trusted it on my phone and then followed your steps to do the full trust. I'm not sure what else to try at this point. The strange thing is that it was working perfectly before fiddler ran an automatic update.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Windows Firewall and try again. I faced the same problem, and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

on step4 try this on your device in Safari:
192.168.162.202:8888
[your ip]:[your port]

Comment: While the suggestion to use the direct IP might help, there are other potential solutions or troubleshooting steps that might be useful, such as:

Checking any firewall settings that might be blocking the iPhone's access.
Ensuring there's no IP address conflict.
Checking if other devices can access the Fiddler certificate page.
Looking for any known issues with the specific Fiddler version.

The answer, as it stands, is a potential step in the right direction but lacks completeness and clarity.